# Making Woocommerce optimized for more than 500k products

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, categories, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a wordpress woocommerce website that has around 500k products. Currently, when I am trying to load products under certain category(around 30k products), it doesn't load and gives me server timeout, when I am trying to load a category with just 83 products, it is taking more than 30 seconds to show the products.

I used query monitor to analyse the queries, it says there are 945 duplicate queries just for category with 83 products. For categories with larger products the page is not loading so query monitor is not able to show results.

I asked my developer for suggestion, he says I will have to buy dedicated server since shared hosting is bad. He is recommending me against optimising my database. I am currently using Bluehost's wordpress customised server with 6 cpus and 10 gb RAM while bluehost is recommending me to optimise my database rather than going for dedicated server.

I don't know much about woocommerce or wordpress, but what can be solutions to the problem? I have wp-super cache enabled, it did improve to some extent. Will building indexes solve my problem for page load time or should I go with dedicated server to reach page load time under 3 seconds?

I would really be grateful if someone can suggest me some alternatives? I don't want to go with magento, instead I want to stay with woocommerce

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce store with ~30,000 products](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/woocommerce-store-with-30-000-products)

Comment: The thing is people have recommended different technologies on that answer, I want to stay with woocommerce.

Comment: That's because each technology has its benefits. While WooCommerce is perfect for small web shops, Magento is an absolute monster for small web shops. I always think you should use the right technology for the thing you want to do. And In my opinion, Woocommerce isn't the technology you want to use on a large dataset.

Comment: Not sure what is the answer you expect. In general it is most likely going to be "your code sucks" which is not a very helpful answer. It is not only your code, because if you have a category with 30k products, then obviously you are doing things wrong.... when getting to this level of DB size and traffic every decision needs to be taken with emphasize on performance. putting caching plugins might help in a way but they will not be a total solution because there is a cost to having those plugins as well. All this said, it sounds like you are not using object caching, which you must.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64593/104427

Although I personally can't recommend Magento, It is the way to go if you have a large set of products/data. In our case, Magento is handling 300.000 products quite well.

Comment: Is it possible to stay with woocommerce? I watched this video https://www.wpintense.com/2016/08/16/scaling-woocommerce-1-million-products-talk-wordcamp-brighton/#comment-25648 but he seems to miss the technicality

Comment: @GokuFrieza I think you should use the right technology for the job you want. And not try to 'hack' or 'optimise' a solution that isn't meant for that purpose. In this case, we wouldn't recommend WooCommerce.